# Eclipse RCP product configuration not adding all required plugins

Tags: configuration, eclipse-rcp

I am in the process of trying to migrate an old Kepler RCP app to an up-to-date platform. The old configuration was based on plugins but I now want to use features and have now grouped the pluging into feature groups. I have also created a Target Platform based on Eclipse 2019-03, BIRT 4.7 and a few other items which are required.

The project configuration is defined to use features and I added the following features (followed by `Add Required`):

[image: Feature list]

When I try to test the product (from the Product Editor) I get a long list of missing constraints:

[image: Missing constraints]

When I open the generated Launch Configuration, I can see on the `Plug-ins` tab that 95 out of 547 plugins are selected. Without changing any settings, if I simply click `Add Required Plug-ins` the total jumps to 226.

My question is: what am I doing wrong so that the Product Configuration cannot resolve the required plug-ins but the Launch Configuration can?

Answer (score 1):

The `org.eclipse.e4.rcp` feature only contains the plug-ins for an e4 based RCP. This type of RCP is very minimal and does not contain any of the plug-ins for the 3.x compatability mode RCP - which are the plug-ins being listed as missing.

You will need to use one of the features which contain the 3.x compatability mode code (maybe `org.eclipse.platform` or `org.eclipse.sdk`).